# Calling sever side method in asp.net

Tags: c#

I am trying to call login() method which is a sever side method through html elment

```
 <div id="LogIn" runat="server" onclick="<%=login() %>"  style="border: medium solid #C0C0C0; font-family: 'Californian FB'; font-style: normal; color: #000000; font-size: larger; font-weight: bold; list-style-type: circle;" >LogIn</div>
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick="<%=login() %>"` syntax is *not* a way to "bind" server-side code into client side code.

What it is, is a way to generate the HTML that will be sent to the browser: server-side the "login()" method is called, then the output is inserted as string into the HTML. Only *then* the resulting HTML is sent to the browser.

This browser has no knowledge of any "server side code" and can't execute it. "server side" and "browser side" are two different worlds that are alternating execution: only one can have control, you can't mix them.

You need to cause a "postback", maybe by using an `<asp:Button>`. That can have a server-side "onclick" event to react to a click on that button.